# Separate URI For Each Step in Azure MFA

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework, multi-factor-authentication

Is it possible to have a separate URI for each step of the MFA in B2C?  Right now as a work around, we are keying off the ajax Success return to provide a unique user experience for each step but it might be cleaner if we don't have to rely on this.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-policies-understanding-contents), we should be able to extend the phonefactor technical profiles, but there aren't any details about this specifically.

**Update**

- Let's assume I have zzz.com/A for a page containing the options: "call me" and "send code."
- Let's say I select "send code", can I then specify zzz.com/B for a page containing, the "Enter your verification code below," input?
- Or perhaps if I select "Call Me" can I send that to zzz.com/C to display another user experience there?

Comment: Hi Justin. Can you please clarify what you are attempting to do from a functional point of view?

Comment: Sure, thanks Chris: Let's assume I have zzz.com/A for a page containing the options: "call me" and "send code."  Let's say I select "send code", can I then specify zzz.com/B for a page containing, the "Enter your verification code below," input?  

Or perhaps if I select "Call Me" can I send that to zzz.com/C to display another user experience there?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett - question updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MFA behaviour (for a custom policy, this is implemented by the `PhoneFactorProtocolProvider` provider) is built to be self-contained that means the call/text interaction can't be separated from the verify interaction.